# Ansible playbook fails to connect to a guest VM. Exception thrown NewConnectionError

Tags: ansible, connection

I have created a playbook to create VM in a vmware Vcenter. It worked fine. I have used my localhost as host to create a vm on this vcenter. Now, I am trying to execute a command on that newly created vm  but I am getting a connection error. The error message shown by my ansible playbook tries to login from the ESX host on which the new vm is deployed. Please help me to resolve this.
my playbook:

```yaml
---
 - name : do opearation on vm
   hosts : rhel66
   vars_files :
      - "playbook_vars.yml"
   tasks :
     - name : Run command inside a vm
       vmware_vm_shell :
              hostname: "{{ vcenter_name }}"
              username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
              password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
              datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
              #folder: AutomationDevelopment/vm/Environments/Env07/rhel66_testvm
              vm_id: "{{ vm_name }}"
              validate_certs : false
              vm_username: root
              vm_password: *******
              vm_shell: /bin/echo
              vm_shell_args: " $var >> myFile "
              vm_shell_env:
                   - "PATH=/bin"
                   - "VAR=test"
              vm_shell_cwd: "/tmp"
       register: shell_command_output
```

playbook output:

```
 ____________________________
< PLAY [do opearation on vm] >
 ----------------------------
 ________________________
< TASK [Gathering Facts] >
 ------------------------|

An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='YY.YY.YY.YY', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /guestFile?id=235&token=52009a00-3927-ee12-8e82-bb795a2332c5235 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4d69e0c0f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',)))
fatal: [XX.XX.XX.XX]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
 ____________
< PLAY RECAP >
 ------------
```

In above error: XX.XX.XX.XX -> my new vm IP and YY.YY.YY.YY is my ESX host on which this new vm is deployed

Answer (score 1):

After dealing with this, and actually answering my own question (asked because there wasn't an answer here), I think your issue is routing. There is no route to host. What I didn't understand initially was that it is trying to connect to the host that the vm is resident on, not the vCenter. Hopefully that helps. I use this for Windows VM's, the connection plugin that is, and it is helpful when trying to install openssh on windows 2016 VMs. It is also helpful when you need to do things prior to connecting the network.